# Docker container not mounting volume properly

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following directory:

```
.
└── wordpress
    └── important-file.txt

1 directory, 1 files
```

**My problem is** that when I run the command below on my local `WSL / Ubuntu`:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd)"/wordpress:/var/www/html php:7.3-fpm-alpine /bin/sh
```

I was expecting to find file: `important-file.txt` inside directory: `/var/www/html`, but the directory was empty.

I tried this on two different local computers and the result was the same. So, if you try it, probably you will get the same result.

**In the other hand**, if I run the same command on a `Digital Ocean` droplet the file is there.

**Local WSL / Ubuntu system:**

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

**Digital Ocean droplet**

```
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

The file sharing of my Docker Desktop looks like:

[image]

Any idea on why I don't get that file on my local `WSL / Ubuntu` system?

Comment: `”$(pwd)”/wordpress` is ambiguous. Just mount `./wordpress’. Also, you tagged this question as docker-compose but it doesn’t seem like you’re using it at all here.

Comment: I tried with: `./wordpress` but it didn't work.

Comment: It doesn’t seem like you’re using docker-compose can you either share the docker-compose.yml or the Dockerfile.

Comment: sorry about that. removed that tag

Comment: Can you share Dockerfile?

Comment: I was not using Dockerfile on both experiments. I was running the docker containers on the fly. On my local computers behave different than on the Digital Ocean droplet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3385#issuecomment-533279510

Specifically what I did was:

1. Give: `docker-users` full control over the directory I want to mount:

[image]

2. On the Windows console, run the command:

```
> icacls wordpress /q /c /t /grant docker-users:F
```

3. Restart the service: `LxssManager`:

[image]

4. Close and ReOpen the `WSL / Ubuntu`.

[image]

5. Try again:

[image]

That did the trick.